# Nirvana & the fall of the 5 Hinderances

Tags: nirvana, five-hindrances

What more is Nirvana than the perminant fall of The Five  Hinderances? Could one perform bad karma with all the hinderances eradicated? What about neutral or even good karma?

Comment: Giving up, the home-task first.

Answer (score 1):

5 Hindrances can be suppressed in Jhana. As one is not yet fully liberated when in Jhana though the 5 Hinadraces are suppressed, one accumulates both positive and negative karma.

Answer (score 0):

**What more is Nirvana than the perminant fall of The Five Hinderances?**

Theravada doctrine is that it's the eradication of the "10 fetters".

[The *Vimuttimagga*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_hindrances#From_post-canonical_Pali_literature) (according to Wikipedia) says that "the five hindrances include all ten fetters".

Comment: Do not misrepresent the Theravadin doctrine please. It's not good to misrepresent the Theravadin doctrine.

Comment: As neither the vimuttimagga nor wikipedia is included in the Theravadin canon it's not clear  why author references it when expressing "the theravadin doctrine"

Comment: @sigh... I didn't know or see that the Viimuttimagga wasn't the Visuddhimagga, thanks for the correction.

Comment: Afaik in the Theravadin doctrine Nibbana is taught by twofold classification; Nibbana, relinquishment through cessation as giving up and Nibbana relinquishment through cessation as entering into. It is also taught as eightfold classification of Nibbana in a qualified sense and as a singlefold classification of Nibbana in a definitive sense. Removal of greed, anger and delusion is spoken of as Nibbana and it is further classified as element with and without residue. These are the definitions by the sutta method and are afaik representative of the Theravadin doctrine.

Comment: The expression "it's the eradication of the 10 fetters" isn't wrong but to say that it's representative of theravadin doctrine isn't correct imo because there is more to it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment again. I wouldn't be able to post such a detailed answer on that topic.